# ServiceNow Cart display on Hover

Tags: cart, servicenow, jelly

I'm working on a ServiceNow project to display cart on button hover in a header section. The display works successfully on Catalog items, but fails on main page. Any thoughts on why the code works one on page, but not the other?

Catalog Item

[image: Catalog Item]

Landing Page

[image: Landing Page]

```
<div id="cart_floating_column" class="">
    <div id="floating_cart_goes_here" class="cms_cart_container">
    </div>
</div>

<j:set var="jvar_use_cart_layouts" value="${gs.getProperty('glide.sc.use_cart_layouts', 'true')}" />
<script>
     <j:if test="${jvar_use_cart_layouts == 'false'}">
         g_cart_proxy = new CartProxy('floating_cart_goes_here');
     </j:if>
     <j:if test="${jvar_use_cart_layouts == 'true'}">
         g_cart_proxy = new CartProxyV2('floating_cart_goes_here');
     </j:if>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using an iFrame with a src to a page:

```
<iframe id="catalog_cart" frameborder="0" src="cart.do"/>
```

We added the page through Content Management -> Pages. The URL Suffix is "cart". Below is the view of "cart.do". We added content by clicking "Add Content" -> "Catalog Catagories" - > "Shopping Cart".

[image]